# SVG: align tip of "marker-end" with end of line

Tags: svg

I'm drawing an SVG line with a "marker-end" to make it an arrow. It draws the arrowhead extending beyond the end of the line, making the whole arrow longer, but I would like the whole arrow to be the same length as the original line. That is, the tip of the arrowhead should be at the endpoint of the line. How do I do that?

Making the line shorter to accommodate the size of the arrowhead won't really work. The size of the arrowhead depends on the thickness of the line (which is good), but I don't know the thickness because it can be specified in a style element that's already been written to the SVG document.

In this example, I'd like the the arrowhead entirely inside the square, with its tip at the square's corner, rather than sticking out of the square.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<g><marker id="arrowhead0" viewBox="0 0 60 60" refX="0" refY="30" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 0 0 L 60 30 L 0 60 z" fill="#800000" /> </marker>
<line marker-end="url(#arrowhead0)" x1="1" y1="1" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="#800000" />
<rect x="1" y="1" width="100" height="100" stroke="green" fill="none"/>
</g></svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `refX` atribute to 60 (which I think might be the width of the arrowhead when oriented pointing to the right) seems to fix this issue. Scaling the width seems to be fine, not sure about other attributes.

I am no SVG expert, just found this interesting and played with the attributes until I stumbled upon this solution, so take it with a grain of salt.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<g><marker id="arrowhead0" viewBox="0 0 60 60" refX="0" refY="30" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 60 30 L 0 60 z" fill="#800000" /> </marker>
   <marker id="arrowhead1" viewBox="0 0 60 60" refX="60" refY="30" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 60 30 L 0 60 z" fill="#800000" /> </marker>
   <marker id="arrowhead2" viewBox="0 0 60 60" refX="60" refY="30" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="16" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 60 30 L 0 60 z" fill="#800000" /> </marker>
<line marker-end="url(#arrowhead0)" x1="1" y1="1" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="#800000" />
<line marker-end="url(#arrowhead1)" x1="1" y1="100" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="#800000" />
<line marker-end="url(#arrowhead2)" x1="100" y1="1" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="#800000" />
<rect x="1" y="1" width="100" height="100" stroke="green" fill="none"/>
</g></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

refX and refY control that so adjust as necessary. E.g.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<g><marker id="arrowhead0" viewBox="0 0 60 60" refX="44" refY="34" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 0 0 L 60 30 L 0 60 z" fill="#800000" /> </marker>
<line marker-end="url(#arrowhead0)" x1="1" y1="1" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="#800000" />
<rect x="1" y="1" width="100" height="100" stroke="green" fill="none"/>
</g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "marker-start" instead of "marker-end", draw the arrowhead backwards, and swap the line's endpoints.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<g><marker id="arrowhead0" viewBox="0 0 60 60" refX="0" refY="30" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 60 0 L 0 30 L 60 60 z" fill="#800000" /> </marker>
<line marker-start="url(#arrowhead0)" x1="100" y1="100" x2="1" y2="1" stroke="#800000" />
<rect x="1" y="1" width="100" height="100" stroke="green" fill="none"/>
</g></svg>
```

Comment: As long as the other end doesn't have a marker. While this is clever, I feel some more detailed explanation of why your solution works would improve this answer.

Comment: Actually, the other answers are much better.

Comment: not working, if you will add stroke-width to the line then it is clearly visible that the line is extending beyond the marker.